# What if the computation inside a listener is slow than the listener's update?

Tags: java, android, listener, sensors

I am a new Android programmer. And I am implementing an algorithm within a sensor listener, that each time the sensor data has been received, I will do some computations base on the newly received sensor data, the code is something like this:

```
class somelistener implements someSensorListener {

    public void onReceive(Item state) {
        // I will do some computation here, and make a change for the UI
    }
}
```

And now I am wondering a question: what if the computation is slower than the sensor data update frequency, that when the newest sensor data arrives, the last round of computation has not been finished? Will it result in a problem?

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 case scenarios:

If the callback is asynchronous then it will spawn a new thread every time the method is called. This means that many of these methods can co-exist at the same time.
If the callback is synchronous then it will spawn in the same thread (this is usually the case). In android this usually means that a Looper (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) will handle this message as soon as the previous message has finished. If the computation of the method is slower than the rate at which new messages are added to the queue of the Looper, this may eventually throw some kind of exception.

Are you sure that your computation takes more time than the rate of callbacks?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Sakis! Until now the computation speed is fast enough to catch up the sensor data update. But as I am adding more and more complicated parts to this, I am not sure whether the speed will still be enough. Just curious of what it will be if such problem happens, and see if there can be any good solutions in case this really happens. But fortunately now it is not happening.

Comment: Can't really be sure about what's gonna happen, the queue with the messages should eventually run out of space. What kind of listener is it? Isn't there a way to ask the listener to update less often ?